# Wifi dropping without notice randomly

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, kubuntu, broadcom

I've seen alot of threads but none with an answer. My wifi connection becomes unresponsive randomly and without notification of disconnect. When checking wireless it's still connected but only shows additional 2 available networks (instead of 10+). I get connection only when I disable/enable wireless.

I'm running 15.10

```
lscpi -vnn | grep Network
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

lsmod
wl                   6365184  0
cfg80211              548864  1 wl
```

I'm using the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package.

What I tried:

1. Disable IPV6
2. Use b43 driver (doesn't recognize card at all)
3. restrict MTU to 1500
4. Assign a static IP by the router

I appreciate your help.